# MouseEventArgs with undesired namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

The ultimate goal is to add tooltips to the objects in a ListBox. I have found a few examples of doing this, namely:

```
private void OnListBoxMouseMove ( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
{
    string strTip = "";

    // Get the item
    int nIdx = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);

    if ((nIdx >= 0) && (nIdx < listBox1.Items.Count))
        strTip = listBox1.Items[nIdx].ToString();

    toolTip1.SetToolTip(listBox1, strTip);
}
```

However, my page is putting this in as `System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs` object instead of a `Systems.Windows.Forms` so `e.Location` does not exist.

Is there anyway to receive this event from the correct namespace? One other factor could be that the ListBox is in the `System.Windows.Controls` namespace?

Comment: This might be useful - [GetPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mouseeventargs.getposition?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Input_MouseEventArgs_GetPosition_System_Windows_IInputElement_)

Comment: System.Windows.Input is wpf, System.Windows.Forms is winforms. You either work with one or the other, but rarely combine both in one window.

Comment: Are you developing a WPF or Windows Forms app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to accomplish the final goal, adding tooltips that are for each individual item in the listbox, I simply added the event handler to the Listbox in the xmal as such.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
         <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="mouseEnterMethodName"></EventSetter>
    </Style>
</ListBoxItemTemplate>
```

Then in the cs simply cast the sender to ListBoxItem, and then just set the ListBoxItem.ToolTip to whatever you want. It was extremely useful to learn that WPF and winforms work in different namespaces. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are using WPF, and this should the the answer you are looking for:

[Displaying a tooltip text on a listbox specific item](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c2e80333-7996-45ef-8acf-5f0a085a21e1/displaying-a-tooltip-text-on-a-listbox-specific-item?forum=winformsdatacontrols)

Text from article:

Hi，if you want to display tooltip on individual items in a ListBox,here is a quick easy way. It doesn't require custom controls and is rather small in code.

First create a method to handle mouse move events, then hook it to the MouseMove event of the ListBox. You will also need a ToolTip object as a member variable for the form. The code required to create and update the tooltip is:

```
private void onMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(sender is ListBox)
    {      
        ListBox listBox = (ListBox)sender;
        Point point = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        int hoverIndex = listBox.IndexFromPoint(point);
        if(hoverIndex >= 0 && hoverIndex < listBox.Items.Count)
        {
            tt.SetToolTip(listBox, listBox.Items[hoverIndex].ToString());
        } 
    }    
}
```

For more information,please check the [end of  this article](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx)

To your second question, you can use [ToolTip.AutomaticDelay Property](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.automaticdelay(VS.71).aspx) .

Comment: An answer that basicly shows just a link to another site/page is not the best thing, above all if solution is short and can be written here. You'd better telling the page you've taken the answer from, but also write the solution directly so users don't need to jump here and there to find what they're searching for. Please also consider that the link you write could go missing in time, while solution written here remains valid!

Comment: @marco thanks for telling me that
Actually I thought that it will consider it as a comment, but site checked it as a answer

Comment: Well, you can still edit your answer trying to improve it :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that example seems to be using the other Forms namespace. I can use e.GetPosition to get a point instead of using e.X and e.Y, but the IndexFromPoint I have not yet found an equivalent